# What is the viability of using telecom DC-ATX converters for a standard desktop computer?

Tags: power-supply

I have gotten mixed feedback about using non-isolated power supplies for a desktop computer. On one hand, the average engineer reaction is "Oh you can't use a non-isolated power supply because you (1) will have ground loops, (2) if connect different computer loads to the same power source bad things will happen, (3) your ethernet and USB connectors will catch on fire, etc etc".

However, it seems that telecom companies and other industrial users seem to be using DC-DC 48v systems routinely to run computers (see example power supply below). These power supplies don't even have fans.

So, if my system is going to explode if I use a non-isolated power supply, how is it that products like the one below even exist?

[image: DC-ATX supply]

[image]

Comment: is that power supply non-isolated?

Comment: @jsotola How else could it be so small and have no fan? Isolated DC to DC power supplies have big transformers in them.

Comment: The transformer in the middle-top of the first image suggests otherwise. It also takes -48 V input, a telecom standard.

Comment: @winny That transformer is tiny. Normal 500W isolated DC-DC power converters are MUCH larger than the unit shown above, have fans, heat sinks and weight about 10x what the thing above does.

Comment: Those must be isolating like standard computer ATX supplies are. You are likely confusing between isolated and floating. ATX supply output does not float, it's earthed/grounded. And yes, even tiny switch mode transformers can isolate. You don't need a big linear power supply for that.

Comment: @Justme ok, well that is the kind of answer I am looking for. I am not an electrical engineer. I am looking for an explanation, that's why I asked the question. I have no idea no difference between isolated and floating.

Comment: No problem pushing 500 W though it. Telecom stuff usually have very high performance stuff and and really small.

Comment: What is meant by isolated? Computer power supplies have all rails referenced to the same 0V which is connected to ground - they are not isolated from each other. Both computer and telecom supplies have to be isolated from the AC input or everything will break (and shock people). So I'm not seeing why they should be different from each other.

Answer (score 1):

The telco power supply, in North America, is a positive ground -48V DC system. Until the advent of cell phones, the dc supply to the passive telephones was not isolated. Modern telephones and their distribution systems require local positive and negative dc power at all the common voltages.

Clearly, the photograph shows a negative dc input with +12V,-12V, 3.3V and two +5V. To achieve these outputs from a single dc input requires a switching converter. The large transformer in the top left together with the two transistors probably form a push-pull isolated converter. It could also be a fly-back converter. The other visible magnetics indicate that the other voltages are also produced switch-mode. The lack of a fan indicates a well designed high efficiency system.

> So, if my system is going to explode if I use a non-isolated power supply, how is it that products like the one below even exist?

Because it is isolated!